# smallest number in the range [l,r] that has maximum number of bits set

Tags: number-theory

We have to find the smallest number in the range [l,r] that has maximum number of bits set .The solution requires some mathematical insight so i posted it on this website instead of stack overflow

The solution simply says this

```
void solve(){
while((l | (l + 1)) <= r){
 l = (l | (l + 1));
}
printf("%I64d\n",l);
}
```

But i coluld not understand as how this solves the problem ? Here l and l means the range [l,r].

Comment: it means we take OR of l with l+1 and we keep doing this till l OR l+1 <=R and when l OR (l+1) is greater than r, we output answer as l

Answer (score 2):

Adding $1$ to an integer $n$ has the effect of setting the rightmost zero bit in its binary representation to $1$. Thus $n = (n\,|\,n + 1)$ sets the rightmost zero bit in the binary representation of $n$. Therefore, the algorithm is sequentially setting the rightmost zero bits and checking that the result is within the range $[l,r]$. Since at each step the rightmost zero bit is set, $l$ is increasing by the minimal amount possible given that its number of set bits is increasing by $1$.